# How to append delurl with more parameters for jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I would like to send a POST url `projInfoOperate.do` with parameter `oper=del&id=123&projType='software'&projNum='111'` after I select a checkbox and press delete button. And these parameter values should be the cell value of selected row.

Currently, just `oper=del&id=123` can be passed to server. How to append other parameters? I tried deldata, it didn`t work. How to implement with jqgrid?

Any suggestion are welcome. Thanks in advance!

```
jQuery("#grid-table").jqGrid(
{
    //...
    colModel : [{
                    name : 'projType',
                    index : 'projType'
                },
                {
                    name : 'projSerialNum',
                    index : 'projSerialNum',
                    key : true
                }, 
                {
                    name : 'projNum',
                    index : 'projNum'
                }, 
                {
                    name : 'remark',
                    index : 'remark'
                }],
    multiselect : true,
    multiboxonly : true,
    shrinkToFit:false,   
    autoScroll: true,
    editurl : "projInfoOperate.do"
});
```

and

```
jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid(
    'navGrid',
    pager_selector,
    { //navbar options
        edit : false,
        editicon : 'icon-pencil blue',
        edittext : "Edit",
        editurl : "projInfoOperate.do",
        del : true,
        delicon : 'icon-trash red',
        deltext : "Delete",
        delurl : "projInfoOperate.do",
    },
    {
        url : "projInfoOperate.do",
        recreateForm : true,
        delData : {

         }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  delData: {
                    projType: function () {

                        return 'software' ;
                    },

                    projNum: function () {

                        return '111' ; 

                    }
                },
```